# Binary data being mangled when transfered in string between functions

Tags: c#, .net, io

hope this is a trivial problem that can be solved easily.

Im trying to move the contents of a binary file from one location to another but with a twist: I need to transfer it as a string and this is where the file ends up a bit different than the source.

The reason for transfer it via a string is that the code that loads a file and the code that saves a file is only communicating through a host (this is a C# MEF application) and the interface forces me to send data via a string, nothing else.

So what I'm doing is this (pseudo'ish, only core functionality remains):

```
// This part loads a binary file

string output = string.Empty; // The data to be transfered
byte[] fileContent; // The binary file content

fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

output = Encoding.Default.GetString(fileContent);
//output = Convert.ToBase64String(fileContent);
//output = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(fileContent);
//output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent);
//output = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(fileContent);
//output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileContent);
//output = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(fileContent);
//output = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(fileContent);
```

Then the string is transfered to its destination part:

```
// This part saves a binary file

string input; // This is the data recieved
byte[] content = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);

File.WriteAllBytes("c:\test.png", content);
```

The destination file now differs a bit from the source file, a byte here and there if I look at the files with a propriate tool. The encoding I'm using in the sending part that works the best is Unicode.

What am I missing here?

Comment: depends on how the string is encoded/decoded during transport. what is it, http? soap? best guess for platform and interface independency might be to use base64 for transmission.

Comment: You have two different encodings for one thing (Encoding.Default and Encoding.Unicode).  But aside from that, why are you converting to string in the first place?  Why not just pass the data back and forth as a byte array?  If you really need to pass the data back and forth as a string, you should probably look into using Base64.

Comment: A string cannot store arbitrary binary data.  If you try anyway then you'll see the side-effects of an encoding of a byte not having a corresponding glyph in Unicode (producing 0x3f or 0xfffd), normalization rules (random corruption) and the occasional hard crash when 2 bytes happen to match a surrogate.  Only Convert.ToBase64String() will keep you out of trouble.

Comment: @HansPassant The example I gave in the answer seems to work. Are there any hidden issues I'm missing? (Besides that I only tested it locally, not across any boundaries)

Comment: Of course, no matter how you produce the string (reliably), the sender and receiver have to process in the same but opposite ways. I assume you control both. Repeating, Convert.ToBase64String() keeps any character encoding issues in the communication channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like was said in the comments, the safest option is using Base-64. But if you want a little more efficiency, any simple 8-bit encoding without gaps should work, as long as you use the same encoding to decode it. By simple I mean not any of the Unicode multi-byte encodings. And I believe ASCII also won't work since it's 7-bit.

Note on efficiency: Each byte is actually being stored in 2 bytes since strings in C# are stored internally in unicode. But with Base-64 you are using 8 bytes for every 3 bytes of the binary.

I Tried using `Encoding.GetEncoding(437)` and it worked on a local system:

```
var b = new byte[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    b[i] = (byte)i;

var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
var s = encoding.GetString(b);
var b2 = encoding.GetBytes(s);

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    if (b2[i] != i)
        Console.WriteLine("Error at " + i);
```

Comment: Some simple 8-bit encodings have gaps and could therefore throw on encoding.

Comment: @JonHanna you're right, adding that to the answer. That's why I used 437 instead of [ISO_8859-1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1), which appears to have gaps.

Comment: .NET takes "ISO 8859-1" to mean the IANA registered  ISO-8859-1 which is  ISO_8859-1:1987 which fills all of those gaps with CO and C1 control codes (and which for each character code-point identical with the octet value) so in fact `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetChars(Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray()).Select(c => (int)c).SequenceEqual(Enumerable.Range(0, 256))` returns true making it the most straightforward to use. The older form of 8859-1 is a good example of where it wouldn't work, though.

Comment: Yes the main trick was, ofcourse(!), using Base-64 at both ends. I'm used to using Base-64 in web-aps for safely sending data between web/services/documents, but didn't think it was the first thing I had to do before landing the data in a string. But now when I think about it, it makes sense.

Thanks for the help, I realy appreciate it!